# Android local and remote file access

Tags: server, android, ftp, remote

I have 4 nexus 10 Tablets, and 3 Android phones. I would like to be able to back them up (locally for speed), and pull files from the back up from anywhere (over cellular data connection). What type of server/s would I use and how would I go about setting it up. I did a bunch of looking around and have no idea what direction to go.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, you can setup a SFTP/SSH server in a Ubuntu machine. Then, you need to open a port(default port 22 for ssh service, can be changed to other port) on the router so that it can direct all external calls to your server. Record the public IP granted by the router.

On your SFTP server, you need to create an special account which will be used for login by remote machines(the mobile devices). Apply some constraints on this account so that people using this can only access the folders and files kept by it but not other things.

On the clients side (your mobile devices), you may install a file manager such as ES File Explorer which can act as a sftp client. Use the IP and the sftp account created previously to access your server.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. SSH keys, rsync from the desktops/laptops, foldersync for the android devices(sftp client), and ES file explorer for access to the backups. Been going strong for almost 3 years now :D

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at git-annex which are used for syncronize files between different machines, servers and cloud storages.
It works with Android, MS Windows and Linux/Unix machines. There are no client for iOS devices. 
Notice that it isn't a backup solution, it's a synchronisation tool. Look at pub for a backup tool based on git.